# Choose between 2 designs on product page

Tags: product, css, html, design, product-page

On the shops im admin on, the users want different designs on some products. And the admin before me have made an css for each product so far.

I was wondering is there a way the user can choose what design they want on that product page?

Like in wordpress you choose what template the post/page should use.

Comment: by user you mean admin?

Comment: I mean im the IT guy (admin), and the other guys in the firm are the users(user). they put in product and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

products (and categories) support different designs.
All you have to do is to create 2 different magento themes. They don't need to be completely different. One can inherit the other and you can only change the product view template and/or css.
Then you can select one or the other theme in the "Design" tab when adding/editing a product. You should see in that tab a dropdown called "Custom design".  You can select the theme from there for each product.
If you create 2 themes, one is going to be default and you need to select a different theme only for the products that you want to look different.